# How to split out tagged column from df and fill new column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a column in a Python df like:

```
TAGS
{user_type:active}
{session_type:session1}
{user_type:inactive}
```

How can I efficiently make this column its own column for each of the tags specified?

Desired:

```
       TAGS            |user_type|session_type
{user_type:active}     |active   |null
{session_type:session1}|null     |session1
{user_type:inactive}   |inactive |null
```

My attempt only is able to do this in a boolean sense (not what I want) and only if I specify the columns from the tags (which I don't know ahead of time):

```
mask = df['tags'].apply(lambda x: 'user_type' in x)
df['user_type'] = mask
```

Answer (score 0):

there are better ways but this is from what you got

```
df['user_type'] = df['tags'].apply(lambda x: x.split(':')[1] if 'user_type' in x else np.nan)
df['session_type'] = df['tags'].apply(lambda x: x.split(':')[1] if 'session_type' in x else np.nan)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [pandas.json_normalize()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) to convert `TAGS` column to dict object and check if `user_type` is a key of that dict.

```py
df2 = pd.json_normalize(df['TAGS'])
df2['user_type'] = df2['TAGS'].apply(lambda x: x['user_type'] if 'user_type' in x else 'null')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what ended up working for me, wanted to post a short working example from the json library the helped.

```
def js(row):
  if row:
    return json.loads(row)
  else:
    return {'':''}

#This example includes if there was/wasn't a dataframe with other fields including tags
import json
import pandas as pd
df2 = df.copy()
#Make some dummy tags
df2['tags'] = ['{"user_type":"active","nonuser_type":"inactive"}']*len(df2['tags'])
df2['tags'] = df2['tags'].apply(js)
df_temp = pd.DataFrame(df2['tags'].values.tolist())
df3 = (pd.concat([df2.drop('tags', axis=1), df_temp], axis=1))
```

@Ynjxsjmh your approach reminds me of something like that I had used in the past, but in this case, I had gotten the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'values'
```

@Bing Wang I am a big fan of list comprehension but in this case I don't know the names of the columns before hand.